# What do FLAGS register components mean in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, visual-studio-2013

When debugging x86 assembly code in VS2013, I needed to check the contents of the FLAGS register. However, when I've enabled "Flags" in Register Window, I got:

```
OV = 0 UP = 0 EI = 1 PL = 1 ZR = 0 AC = 1 PE = 0 CY = 1
```

Those don't correspond to typical `ODITSZAPC` flags of x86; can anyone explain to me what's going on? Are those just weird names for the same flags?

I have a 64-bit Core i7; can it affect the displayed names?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
| Overflow  | OV |
| Direction | UP |
| Interrupt | EI |
| Sign      | PL |
| Zero      | ZR |
| Auxiliary | AC |
| Parity    | PE |
| Carry     | CY |
```

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwydd1t7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course they are the same flags, what else?

But those really are misleading. When UP=1 it's actually reverse back direction (STD), also when PL=1 it's actually sign/negative. Why did VS designer tried to break ASM-thing that ain't broken for ages was beyond my comprehension though.

The same way in GNU's gdb, they called instruction pointer (IP) as $pc, DWORD/DD as word (w), WORD/DW as half-word (h), and QUADWORD/DQ as (g) from GIANT??

C++ Programmers are really weird, they liked to break convention for the sake of it.